# Is there any built-in functionality available in ANTLR4 for the Symbol Table creation?

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, lexer

In my Compiler construction for my language, i've used `ANTLR-v4` for Lexer and Parser. and now i am working on the `Semantic phase`. In the Semantic phase, i required the Symbol table for type checking and Scope of variables. 
**kindly suggest me any libraries other than ANTLR to build symbol table and build the semantic analyzer.**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: A similar question about tools for semantic analysis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694806/what-are-the-tools-for-semantic-analysis-phase-of-compiler-construction